# File Upload server polling with Progress Bar

Tags: jquery, file, upload, progress-bar

This is not a duplicate of those questions that ask how to upload a file and display a progress bar. My understanding of the basics is:

1. We have a form that posts the given input file to the given url.
2. As soon as the submit button is clicked, we set interval to run a Javascript method every second, which uses AJAX to poll the server to get the status of this download.

The only dilemma for me here is that I tried this method, but when I look at FireBug console, I can see all these jQuery AJAX calls. I've seen other people's implementation, where you don't see anything in FireBug > Net > XHR.

Does anyone have any ideas how this is implemented?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Mosh

PS: Just to emphasize, I'm not interested in doing this with Flash.

Comment: Do you think anybody actually implemented this?

Comment: Which programming language are you using? There are some options in PHP for instance, but that doesn't help you when you're using ASP ;-)

Comment: Are you actually asking: **How to hide Ajax requests from Console panel**?

Answer (score 2):

### Not as simple as it seems

I think this would involve some low level web server programming, because files are being processed (uploaded) before your code gets executed. This simply means that you don't have an insight into web server's internall file uploading process to poll/investigate it...

If your scenario should actually work as:

1. select a file
2. submit it (which starts uploading)
3. Ajax poll

then you'd have several problems here:

- if your Ajax requests are supposed to run from the same page, this won't work, because page has already unloaded (form is already being sent) this means that scripts are likely being stopped.
- if you do have your form with file upload in a different `iframe` and poll uploading from parent page, you'd have to implement some of the low level server code to provide what I've highlighted above.

### Client-side plugins

That's why it's much easier to do this on the client side using plugins like [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) that may as well use Flash to get information about upload progress toward the server.

Answer (score 1):

simple :

http://www.uploadify.com/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this page can help you out: [jquery ajax uploader plugin with progress bar](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/). Or you can search for an alternative yourself.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to actually be several questions in one.

- One improvement I can suggest is to use the [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) library, it uses websockets, and fallbacks to long-polling via XHR, or via Flash. It would at least provide a structured way of minimizing polling overhead.
- When it comes the "hidden requests" they probably use a different method than XHR, if you are not seeing the XHR's, they are probably not doing XHR's. (That's kind of obvious)